# How do I succinctly assert that an object has a specific property?

Tags: typescript

I'm converting ASP.NET WebForms' `Focus.js` (it's embedded in `System.Web.dll`) into TypeScript (because I'm maintaining a WebForms project that makes heavy-use of ASP.NET WebForms' stock client-side scripts).

Here's the original JavaScript function `WebForm_IsInVisibleContainer` from `Focus.js`:

```
function WebForm_IsInVisibleContainer(ctrl) {
    var current = ctrl;
    while((typeof(current) != "undefined") && (current != null)) {
        if (current.disabled ||
            ( typeof(current.style) != "undefined" &&
            ( ( typeof(current.style.display) != "undefined" &&
                current.style.display == "none") ||
                ( typeof(current.style.visibility) != "undefined" &&
                current.style.visibility == "hidden") ) ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        if (typeof(current.parentNode) != "undefined" &&
                current.parentNode != null &&
                current.parentNode != current &&
                current.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() != "body") {
            current = current.parentNode;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I've annotated it into this TypeScript:

```
function WebForm_IsInVisibleContainer( ctrl: HTMLElement ): boolean {
    var current = ctrl;
    while( ( typeof ( current ) != "undefined" ) && ( current != null ) ) {
        if( current.disabled ||
            ( typeof ( current.style ) != "undefined" &&
                ( ( typeof ( current.style.display ) != "undefined" &&
                    current.style.display == "none" ) ||
                    ( typeof ( current.style.visibility ) != "undefined" &&
                        current.style.visibility == "hidden" ) ) ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        if( typeof ( current.parentNode ) != "undefined" &&
            current.parentNode != null &&
            current.parentNode != current &&
            (current.parentNode as HTMLElement).tagName.toLowerCase() != "body" ) {
            current = current.parentNode;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

However `tsc` has two compiler errors:

- TS2339 (TS) Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
- TS2740 (TS) Type 'Node & ParentNode' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 178 more.

My quick-fix is to add these type-assertions (below), however this feels like I'm doing something wrong. Especially because `ctrl` could be `HTMLSelectElement` or `HTMLTextAreaElement` which are not `HTMLInputElement` but do have the `disabled: boolean` property:

```
function WebForm_IsInVisibleContainer( ctrl: HTMLElement ): boolean {
    var current = ctrl;
    while( ( typeof ( current ) != "undefined" ) && ( current != null ) ) {
        if( ( current as HTMLInputElement ).disabled ||                                // <-- here
            ( typeof ( current.style ) != "undefined" &&
                ( ( typeof ( current.style.display ) != "undefined" &&
                    current.style.display == "none" ) ||
                    ( typeof ( current.style.visibility ) != "undefined" &&
                        current.style.visibility == "hidden" ) ) ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        if( typeof ( current.parentNode ) != "undefined" &&
            current.parentNode != null &&
            current.parentNode != current &&
            (current.parentNode as HTMLElement).tagName.toLowerCase() != "body" ) {
            current = current.parentNode as HTMLElement;                                // <-- and here
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In JavaScript, it's perfectly fine to use `if( current.disabled )` to check for the existence of a property - why can't TypeScript support this?

I know another workaround is to add a new interface like so:

```
interface DisableableHTMLElement extends HTMLElement {
    disabled: boolean;
}

function WebForm_IsInVisibleContainer( ctrl: DisableableHTMLElement ): boolean {
    // etc
}
```

...but this feels worse, and also isn't succint.

So how can I do something like this in TypeScript:

```
function doSomething( foo: Element ): string {
    if( 'type' in foo ) {
        return foo.type as string;
    }
}
```

(When I do use the above `doSomething` code, TypeScript says the type of `foo` inside the `if()` block is actually `never` instead of `Element`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `current`, if it may have a property `disabled`, will be one of `HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement  | HTMLTextAreaElement`, then I think the best thing to do would be to create a type guard for that:

```
const isDisableableElement = (current: HTMLElement): current is HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement  | HTMLTextAreaElement => {
    return 'disabled' in current;
};
```

It's not *incredibly* concise, but like you said:

> My quick-fix is to add these type-assertions (below), however this feels like I'm doing something wrong. Especially because `ctrl` could be `HTMLSelectElement` or `HTMLTextAreaElement` which are not `HTMLInputElement` but do have the `disabled: boolean` property

You have to choose between conciseness and type-correctness, and type-correctness is probably a better option, especially since it doesn't add that much more code, is straightforward, and has less chance of confusing future readers.

Then, just check the type guard in the condition before checking the `.disabled` property:

```
if (
    (isDisableableElement(current) && current.disabled) ||
```

It looks like you can also trim down the other checks in the code, if you want. If the `ctrl` parameter is typed correctly and will always be an `HTMLElement`, it (and its parents) will always have a `style` property with `display` and `visibility` sub-properties. `current` will never be `undefined` or `null` either, since you're doing those checks at the bottom of the loop already (and a `.parentNode` won't be `undefined` anyway - it'll only ever be an element or `null`). The code should never reach past the end of the loop - either a hidden parent will be found and `false` will be returned, or the final parent will be found and `true` will be returned:

```
function WebForm_IsInVisibleContainer(ctrl: HTMLElement): boolean {
    let current = ctrl;
    while (true) {
        if (
            (isDisableableElement(current) && current.disabled) ||
            current.style.display === 'none' ||
            current.style.visibility === 'hidden'
        ) {
            return false;
        }
        if (current.parentNode !== null &&
            current.parentNode !== current &&
            (current.parentNode as HTMLElement).tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'body'
        ) {
            current = current.parentNode as HTMLElement;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```